# Unable to install Lime (HaxeFlixel)

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel, haxelib, lime-haxe

I'm installing HaxeFlixel by the Getting Started guide (http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/getting-started/).

When I type `haxelib install lime`, it return:

`You already have lime version 1.0.1 installed
[file_contents,C:\Program Files\Stencyl\plaf\haxe\lib/lime/.current]`

and nothing happened.

I also uninstalled Stencyl program but it still return that although the `C:\Program Files\Stencyl\...` doesn't exist.

Comment: That is exactly what happened to me with this Stencyl program, it totally killed my haxe environment somehow..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to say that in comment but have not enougth reputation...

You can try `haxelib path lime` to see the path where is lime.
If it's tell you that it's already in your computer then this should already work.

You can also, check your haxelib path, by typing `haxelib config` this will tell you the directory setup for the libraries.

But you can also do `haxelib remove lime`, to remove the previous version of lime on your computer. And then try to reinstall it. Like that, you are starting with a brand new lime installation.

Answer (score 1):

I found out an file in the folder C:\Users\YourUserHere.haxelib delete it and you should be good to go.

Comment: if he do that, will the OP be able to run the command `haxelib install lime` again?

Comment: Yes, it happens that this ".haxelib" file somehow contained a path to the inexistent stencyl folder. I had the same problem:
1. type `haxelib remove lime`
2. delete the C:\Users\YourUserHere\.haxelib
3. run the command `haxelib install lime`
4. to confirm type `haxelib path lime` it should be in a folder that is not the stencyl one